# Pytest - run multiple tests from a single file

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'm using Pytest (Selenium) to execute my functional tests. I have the tests split across 2 files in the following structure:

My_Positive_Tests.py

```
class Positive_tests:


  def test_pos_1():
    populate_page()
    check_values()

  def test_pos_2():
    process_entry()
    validate_result()
```

My_Negative_Tests.py

```
class Negative_tests:
  def test_neg_1
    populate_page()
    validate_error()
```

The assertions are done within the functions (check_values, validate_result, validate_error).
I'm trying to find a way to run all the tests from a single file, so that the main test file would look something like:

My_Test_Suite.py

```
test_pos_1() 
test_pos_2()
test_neg_1()
```

Then from the command line I would execute:

```
py.test --tb=short "C:\PycharmProjects\My_Project\MyTest_Suite.py" --html=report.html
```

Is it possible to do something like this? I've been searching and haven't been able to find out how to put the calls to those tests in a single file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to run your tests manually. [Pytest finds and executes them automatically](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules):

```
# tests/test_positive.py
def test_pos_1():
    populate_page()
    check_values()

def test_pos_2():
    process_entry()
    validate_result()
```

and

```
# tests/test_negative.py
def test_neg_1():
    populate_page()
    validate_error()
```

If you then run

```
py.test
```

They should automatically be picked up.

You can then also select a single file

```
py.test -k tests/test_negative.py
```

or a single test

```
py.test -k test_neg_1
```

Comment: I tried running py.test from the directory that the tests are in, but then the output was "no tests ran in 0.03 seconds"

Comment: Do you have the `test_` prefix on both files and functions?

Comment: Yes. If you're confused, I explained it with as much detail as I could

Comment: Well, did you try what I wrote? Remove all classes etc. Because that is how **pytest is supposed to work**. Whatever you are trying is against pytest's design.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I didn't have the tests prefixed with "test_". Once I did that and removed the classes it worked perfectly.

Comment: what if I wanted to have sequenced run for the test? e.g: wanted to execute file: test_one.py then test_two.py ?

Comment: @Kedar.Aitawdekar please ask this in a new **Question**

Answer (score 6):

## Start file names and tests with either `test_` or end with `_test.py`. Classes should begin with `Test`

Directory example:
|-- files
|--|-- stuff_in stuff
|--|--|-- blah.py
|--|-- example.py
|
|-- tests
|--|-- stuff_in stuff
|--|--|-- test_blah.py
|--|-- test_example.py

In terminal: `$ py.test --cov=files/ tests/` or just `$ py.test tests/` if you don't need code coverage. The test directory file path must be in your current directory path. Or an exact file path ofcourse

With the above terminal command (`$ py.test tests/`), pytest will search the **tests/** directory for all files beginning with `test_`. The same goes for the file.

test_example.py

```
# imports here

def test_try_this():   
    assert 1 == 1
# or
class TestThis:
    assert 1 == 0
# or even:
def what_test():
    assert True
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the class name

```
class Positive_tests: to--> class Test_Positive:
```

The class name should also start with "Test" in order to be discovered by Pytest. If you don't want to use "Test" in front of your class name you can configure that too, official doc [here](https://pytest.org/latest/customize.html#confval-python_classes)